# How to compare dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a row with date column in my table:

```
date1 = 2013-12-11 00:00:00.000
```

And I want to compare it with date:

```
date2 = 11.12.2013 0:00:00
```

I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM ServiceOrder 
WHERE CreateDateTime <= '11.12.2013 0:00:00'
```

And I am expecting that as a result I get a row with `date1` but I don't get it.

How to compare this dates correctly?

**UPDATE**

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM ServiceOrder 
WHERE CreateDateTime<= CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),'11.12.2013 0:00:00', 121)
```

But same result.

**UPDATE2**

```
SELECT *
FROM ServiceOrder 
WHERE CreateDateTime <= REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),'11.12.2013', 111),'/','-')
```

Does not work, either.

**UPDATE3**

```
SELECT *
FROM ServiceOrder 
WHERE CreateDateTime <= CONVERT(datetime,'11.12.2013 0:00:00', 104)
```

Does not work, either.

Comment: As you see your dates are with different pattern. Use same pattern and you will have no issues

Comment: You will have to convert your date. Here is a link that you can use to find the proper convert method: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: @jorgeCampos : i tried cnvert date but not help. I add query into question/

Comment: thats because the `121` value doesn't fit to the format you have. It most likely you have to use one of the options to break down your string then remount it in an accepted format to convert it. I will try here.

Comment: The hour part of your string date is always 0:00:00 because if it is it will be easier. And if it isn't i'm assuming that is 24h format right?

Comment: @jorgecampos : Can i convert this dates to format without time part? Its possible?

Comment: `WHERE CreateDateTime<='2013-12-11'` work for me..

Comment: @har07 : i tried to convet in your format but not help.

Comment: How do you store these dates ? Do you use a [SMALL]]DATE[TIME][2][OFFSET] column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is a bit tricky to convert your format because it is too specific and ms sql doesn't have easy date format functions to do it. so here is an way to convert your entire date:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ServiceOrder 
 WHERE CreateDateTime <= (
                         select convert(datetime, 
                          concat(y,'-',m,'-',d,' ',h), 20) as dtConverted
                         from ( select substring(dt,1,2) d,
                                       substring(dt,4,2) m,
                                       substring(dt,7,4) y,
                                       substring(dt,12,10) h
                                  from (select 
                                         '11.12.2013 13:00:00' dt) as value
                               ) as convDate
                        )
```

To convert just to a date without time it would be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ServiceOrder 
 WHERE convert(date, CreateDateTime , 104) <= convert(date, 
                               substring('11.12.2013 0:00:00',1,10), 104 )
```

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3787b/1

Comment: I will use tour second expression. Think just dates will enoght. Thanks for help)

Answer (score 1):

Use this. You need to convert the string into datetime for right comparison. And also use the correct format number here 104

```
SELECT *
FROM ServiceOrder 
WHERE CreateDateTime<=CONVERT(datetime,'11.12.2013 0:00:00', 104)
```

And the better practice is that to take a variable and use that in query instead of converting them in query. Like this

```
Declare @CompareDate as DateTime
SET @CompareDate=CONVERT(datetime,'11.12.2013 0:00:00', 104)

    SELECT *
    FROM ServiceOrder 
    WHERE CreateDateTime<=@CompareDate
```

Comment: I tried out example but got same result. Still `date1 > date2`.

Comment: What is the datatype of the field CreateDateTime in the table ServiceOrder ?

Answer (score 1):

You should stick with same date time constant format.

Check out **SET DATEFORMAT**.

Sets the order of the month, day, and year date parts for interpreting date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2 and datetimeoffset character strings.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx.

Default format is month, day, year.

TSQL is smart enough to know that date1 is not in the default format since 2013 can not be a month.  So it interprets it as 11 DEC 2013.

Date 2 has both the month and day in acceptable ranges.  So you get 12 NOV 2013.  Therefore nothing is returned from the where clause in your TSQL statement.

Check half way down on this page, it shows acceptable literal strings for date time in both numeric and alpha-numeric format.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Lets cap this off with a little test program.  Simple table, three months (OCT, NOV, DEC) of the 11th day.  It returns only one date that is less than 10 NOV 2013.  Correct answer.

```
-- use temp db
use tempdb;
go

-- simple test table
create table my_test
( my_date datetime );

-- add 3 rows
insert into my_test values ('2013-12-11 00:00:00.000');
insert into my_test values ('2013-11-11 00:00:00.000');
insert into my_test values ('2013-10-11 00:00:00.000');

-- show the data
select * from my_test;

-- just show october
select * from my_test where my_date < '2013-11-10';
```

[image]

I hope this helps you out.